# Bash script that index's document root. Using echo to run some Javascript, error variable is command not found

Tags: javascript, html, bash

Bash script that index's document root. Using echo to run some Javascript, I get the coolest error that the javascript variable is actually  command not found when script is ran.

```
# print the html header
echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">';
echo "<html><head><title>Index of http://${DOMAIN}${SUBDIR}</title><link href='styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /><script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script> <script type='text/javascript' src='images/jquery.google_menu.js'></script><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='google_menu.css'/><script> $('document').ready(function(){ $('.menu').fixedMenu();  }); </script> </head>";
```

Response I get is: 
./directory-index-images.sh: line 51: document: command not found
./directory-index-images.sh: line 51: .menu: command not found

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Dollar sign has special meaning to the shell, as does `$(...)`. If you want to echo a dollar sign directly, you have to escape it with a back slash:

```
% echo "$(document)"
bash: document: command not found...

% echo "\$(document)"
$(document)
```

Comment: Single quotes could also be used to surround string `$ echo '$abc'$FN'def'`